# Embedding local PDF file in R flexdashboard:runtime:shiny

Tags: r, flexdashboard

I need to display a pdf file from my local machine in the dashboard which I have built using R-Flexdashboard (runtime:shiny). 
Please help how can I do the same.

```
shiny::include_graphics("C:/Users/mykum/Documents/R-Flexdashboard/BA-Project/www/Process_Flow.pdf")
```

Comment: Can you use `shiny::tags$a(href="Process_Flow.pdf")`?

Comment: Yeah, just checked..still not working..

Comment: When you say "need to display", do you mean *"show the first page of the PDF as a png/jpeg"*? Or do you mean *"make a local-filesystem downloadable by the user"*?